# Cassandra column family for Composite Columns?

Tags: java, cassandra, composite

I am designing the Column Family for our use case in Cassandra. I am planning to go with Dynamic Column Structure.

Below is my requirement per our use case-

```
user-id   column1                                        column2                                     column3
123      (Column1-Value  Column1-SchemaName  LMD)       (Column2-Value Column2-SchemaName  LMD)     (Column3-Value  Column3-SchemaName  LMD)
```

For each user-id, we will be storing column1 and its value and that value will store these three things always-

```
(Column1-Value   Column1-SchemaName     LMD)
```

In my above example, I have show only three columns but it might have more columns.

Now I am not sure, how to store these three thing always at a column value level? Should I use composite columns at a column level? if yes, then I am not sure how to make a column family like this in Cassandra.

```
Column1-value will be in binary, Column1-SchemaName will be String, LMD will be DateType.
```

This is what I have so far-

```
create column family USER_DATA
with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and gc_grace = 86400
and column_metadata = [ {column_name : 'lmd', validation_class : DateType}];
```

Can anyone help me in designing the column family for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TechGeeky

Change the comparator to :

```
comparator = 'CompositeType(ByteType,UTF8Type,DateType)'
```

ByteType for Column-Value

UTF8Type for Column-SChemaName

DateType for LMD

Be careful though, with this design, querying your data other than by user-id would be hard. Especially you would be able to get slices of columns by providing column data (in bytes), if you know them before hand...

Comment: I am confuse with this approach.. `comparator` is for column name.. Right? But I need composite values.. Each columns will have composite values. In my case, I need to have three values inside a single column. And that column name can be `e1`, `e2` or `e3` or anything in my case..

Comment: "comparator is for column name.. Right?" --> Exact. In this case your column name will be a composite value of v1:v2:v3. v1 is a byte[], v2 is a string and v3 is a date

Comment: I see but what I need is - columnName should be single string like `e1` and column value should be a composite value of `v1:v2:v3`. `v1` is a byte[], `v2` is a string and `v3` is a date. Is this possible to do?

Comment: " column value should be a composite value of v1:v2:v3" --> In this case, create in Java a class that encapsulate v1,v2 & v3. Then serialize this class as JSON. You could store this JSON payload by defining column value type as UTF8Type

Comment: Thanks doanduyhai for the suggestion. That was my last solution to serialize everything as JSON. But is there any way to use any feature of Cassandra itself before going this route?

Comment: "But is there any way to use any feature of Cassandra itself before going this route?" -> Sure. You can store v1,v2 & v3 as column name composite themselves like this : 'comparator:v1:v2:v3'. But careful, column name is limited to 64K max

Comment: But the problem with this is-... You are saying, save them as the column name but then what I am going to store in the values?

Comment: " what I am going to store in the values?" -> Empty string

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use CQL3.  If you use Cassandra 1.2+ and CQL3, the following table will result in the partition (row) layout you describe.

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    userid text,
    data bytes,
    schema_name string,
    lmd timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, data, schema_name, lmd)
)
```

You can see the following article for more information on how CQL3 ends up as composite columns under the hood, and makes them much easier to use:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts